# Editing posts at the same time

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I edited the same post with the same changes 3-4 times already, but the op keeps changing a few characters in his post, rejecting my edit. Is there any way for me to change the post or stop the mass of rejected edits filling my edit history?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/167548/anonymous?tab=activity see here

Comment: Yes, stop trying to edit the post. The edits were all rejected automatically because they conflicted with the OP's intended improvements. For the future, I strongly advise that you don't make (*repeated*) attempts at editing while the OP is overhauling the question for precisely this reason. (For what it's worth, I actually think that [this suggested edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/678687) should absolutely have been rejected. It ignores most of the major issues with the post...).

Comment: op wasn't editing correctly